# react-native Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError on changing default location of index.ios.js

Tags: react-native

I have kept index.ios.js file at src/js folder and used following command to start package manager and run the project using xcode.

```
npm run start -- --root=./src/js
```

But I got following error. What is reason for this type of error and how to solve it?.

```
Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError
loadModuleImplementation
```

[image]

Following is code details

index.ios.js

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  NavigatorIOS,
} from 'react-native';

import Login from './../../app/components/login/Login';

export default class Hello extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS ref="nav"
                    itemWrapperStyle={styles.navWrap}
                    style={styles.nav}
                    initialRoute={{
                      title: "Login",
                      component: Login
                    }}/>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navWrap: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 70,
  },
  nav: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#48BBEC'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Hello',() => Hello);
```

.bablerc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native"
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you post index.ios.js file.

Comment: Sure, added index.ios.js file.

Comment: try to remove export default and run again.

Comment: tried, same error.

Comment: Tried approach given in http://www.frontendjunkie.com/2016/04/changing-entry-javascript-file-of-your.html, it worked. do we have any better approach?

Comment: I didn't realize that your file was in src folder. Instead of changing location in appdelegate file I would leave it as it is and directly navigate .index file to a file in src or wherever.

Comment: Yaa, I also didn't like to change AppDelegate.m file. Would use the default root location for now unless didn't get some better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you when I use "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator" in my project. I solved this by replace the helper, find at /node_modules/react-native/packager/react packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/babelHelpers.js

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4844#issuecomment-191282653

Hope it useful for you.